# Build version number for testing

Tags: maven, testing, build, integration-testing

I have a web application project which is build using maven script. But unfortunately increment the build version number in POM file in every build is not allowed.

We have a requirement to generate a build version number every time we share a build to testing team. Testing team can be verified the number, If tester cannot see the version then the build will be simply rejected.

What is the best way to handle this.

1. Shall i add a version number to the web page, which can be seen by the testers to verify the number.
2. I do not have any other solution now.

Comment: You can either use the information from your version control system or from your continious integration system which can be added to any kind of file like MANIFEST.MF file. [Take a look here](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2014/01/02/version-information-into-your-appas-with-maven/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through the resources plugin in maven: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

The file being filtered can be a properties file, which will be read by the system, or it could be a properties file which gets the value during release (Jenkins param build) or it could be branded directly into a web page.

Comment: Would adding it in a webpage is a good idea. This web site is a banking website. Whether it will fit to enterprise standard?

Comment: If you are asking if that follows known standards then yes. It is common practice. The web page is normally known as a heartbeat page. You call the page and the page returns the version number. So you can assert that the system is alive (because the page returned content) and which version it has.